# How to make environments (tabular, multicols, etc.) hug the inner margin and not the left margin?

Tags: margins, multicol, books

I am currently reading [LaTeX: A Document Preparation System, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201529831) by Leslie Lamport, and for learning purposes am trying to recreate certain structures present in the book.

For instance, in the book the author uses two-column sections to show the code (right column) and the output of the code (left column).
Below is a screenshot of an example:
[image: Two-column section]

The problem is that I can't recreate the same structure (I am using the `multicol` package for this, with the `verbatim` environment in the right column) while using the `book` document class, because on even-numbered pages the two-column section is hugging the left margin.
When the code in the right column is longer than half of `\textwidth`, it gets printed inside the inner margin (example below, lines with black squares).
[image: Bad margins for two-column section]

The same happens with tables (made with `tabular`) which are longer than `\textwidth` (example below).
[image: Bad margins for tables]

In all of these cases I would like to make these environments hug the inner margin (right margin for even-numbered pages and left margin for odd-numbered pages) and print the leftover part in the outer margins.
Of course, this should happen only when the width of the environment is bigger than `\textwidth`.

EDIT: Added a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{multicols}{2}\scriptsize
  \noindent
  An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.\\
  A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.\\
  A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).\\
  \columnbreak
\begin{verbatim}
An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.
A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.
A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).
\end{verbatim}
\end{multicols}

\blindtext

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
  \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l | l |}
    \hline
    \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}   & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    \\
    \hline
    \verb|\textup| & \verb|\upshape| & \verb|\textsc| & \verb|\scshape|  & \verb|\textrm| & \verb|\rmfamily| \\
    \verb|\textit| & \verb|\itshape| & \verb|\textmd| & \verb|\mdseries| & \verb|\textsf| & \verb|\sffamily| \\
    \verb|\textsl| & \verb|\slshape| & \verb|\textbf| & \verb|\bfseries| & \verb|\texttt| & \verb|\ttfamily| \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\blindtext

\begin{multicols}{2}\scriptsize
  \noindent
  An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.\\
  A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.\\
  A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).\\
  \columnbreak
\begin{verbatim}
An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.
A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.
A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).
\end{verbatim}
\end{multicols}

\blindtext

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
  \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l | l |}
    \hline
    \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}   & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    \\
    \hline
    \verb|\textup| & \verb|\upshape| & \verb|\textsc| & \verb|\scshape|  & \verb|\textrm| & \verb|\rmfamily| \\
    \verb|\textit| & \verb|\itshape| & \verb|\textmd| & \verb|\mdseries| & \verb|\textsf| & \verb|\sffamily| \\
    \verb|\textsl| & \verb|\slshape| & \verb|\textbf| & \verb|\bfseries| & \verb|\texttt| & \verb|\ttfamily| \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please edit your question and provide a small but complete working example, beginning with `\documentclass`, demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This uses paracol to reduce the column width rather than deliberately exceeding it elsewhere.  You will also note that this approach lines up with the headers the same as the example.

Interestingly, without the verbatim multicols ignored the `\columnbreak`, but a simple paragraph break did the trick.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[textwidth=6in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paracol}
\twosided
\setcolumnwidth{0.9\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\begin{multicols}{2}\scriptsize
  \noindent
  An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.\\
  A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.\\
  A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).

\noindent 
An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.\\
A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.\\
A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).
\end{multicols}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
  \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l | l |}
    \hline
    \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}   & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    \\
    \hline
    \verb|\textup| & \verb|\upshape| & \verb|\textsc| & \verb|\scshape|  & \verb|\textrm| & \verb|\rmfamily| \\
    \verb|\textit| & \verb|\itshape| & \verb|\textmd| & \verb|\mdseries| & \verb|\textsf| & \verb|\sffamily| \\
    \verb|\textsl| & \verb|\slshape| & \verb|\textbf| & \verb|\bfseries| & \verb|\texttt| & \verb|\ttfamily| \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\begin{multicols}{2}\scriptsize
  \noindent
  An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.\\
  A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.\\
  A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).

\noindent 
An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.\\
A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.\\
A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).
\end{multicols}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
  \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l | l |}
    \hline
    \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}   & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    \\
    \hline
    \verb|\textup| & \verb|\upshape| & \verb|\textsc| & \verb|\scshape|  & \verb|\textrm| & \verb|\rmfamily| \\
    \verb|\textit| & \verb|\itshape| & \verb|\textmd| & \verb|\mdseries| & \verb|\textsf| & \verb|\sffamily| \\
    \verb|\textsl| & \verb|\slshape| & \verb|\textbf| & \verb|\bfseries| & \verb|\texttt| & \verb|\ttfamily| \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

---

It occurred to me that providing translations is what paracol is primarily used for.  I created an new environment (codecols) to handle all the parameter changes needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[textwidth=6.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paracol}
\twosided
\setcolumnwidth{0.8\textwidth}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{codecols}{\par\bigskip
  \parindent=0pt
  \@minipagetrue% remove spacing arund \verbatim
  \scriptsize
  \setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}%
  \twosided[pmb]% do not swap columns
  \begin{paracol}{2}}%
{\end{paracol}
  \twosided
  \setcolumnwidth{0.8\textwidth}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\begin{codecols}
  An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.\\
  A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.\\
  A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).
\switchcolumn
\begin{verbatim}
An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.\\
A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.\\
A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).
\end{verbatim}
\end{codecols}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
  \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l | l |}
    \hline
    \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}   & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    \\
    \hline
    \verb|\textup| & \verb|\upshape| & \verb|\textsc| & \verb|\scshape|  & \verb|\textrm| & \verb|\rmfamily| \\
    \verb|\textit| & \verb|\itshape| & \verb|\textmd| & \verb|\mdseries| & \verb|\textsf| & \verb|\sffamily| \\
    \verb|\textsl| & \verb|\slshape| & \verb|\textbf| & \verb|\bfseries| & \verb|\texttt| & \verb|\ttfamily| \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\begin{codecols}
  An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.\\
  A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.\\
  A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).
\switchcolumn
\begin{verbatim}
An intra-word dash or hyphen, as in X-ray.\\
A medium dash (en-dash) for number ranges, like 1--2.\\
A punctuation dash---like this (also know as em-dash).
\end{verbatim}
\end{codecols}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
  \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l | l |}
    \hline
    \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}   & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    & \textit{cmd}   & \textit{decl}    \\
    \hline
    \verb|\textup| & \verb|\upshape| & \verb|\textsc| & \verb|\scshape|  & \verb|\textrm| & \verb|\rmfamily| \\
    \verb|\textit| & \verb|\itshape| & \verb|\textmd| & \verb|\mdseries| & \verb|\textsf| & \verb|\sffamily| \\
    \verb|\textsl| & \verb|\slshape| & \verb|\textbf| & \verb|\bfseries| & \verb|\texttt| & \verb|\ttfamily| \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\blindtext
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```